# Entity Framework caching with ASP.NET horizontal scale

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, caching, entity-framework-core, horizontal-scaling

Question about scaling ASP.NET & EF Core scaling horizontally.  My understanding is that each EF core application maintains its own cache.
So if I have a single EF entity in my application, and I want to have multiple ASP.NET application instances, is there a common way to ensure that the EF cache (for this single entity) can stay synchronized across the application instances?

I see that there is
https://github.com/VahidN/EFCoreSecondLevelCacheInterceptor
It says that this project can use Redis, acting as distributed cache.

This project mentions that its suggested use case is "global site settings and public data, such as infrequently changing articles or comments".
My use case is frequently-changing data entities with CRUD.

Answer (score 0):

Entity Framework holds its internal state in `DbContext`. That state is NOT used as cache. It's only there to detect if something was changed between creation of the `DbContext` and execution of `SaveChanges` There is no synchronization. DbContext will use it to calculate what query to send and send it inside an SQL transaction. Transactions ensure data consistency. They employ Optimistic Concurrency, so if you SELECT some data out, and try to UPDATE same rows back, but another transaction just overwrote the data that you previously SELECTed the transaction will fail. Failing transaction changes nothing in the database. Also after such failed transaction `DbContext` will NOT be updated so it's completely pointless to keep it alive. This approach works great with this one assumption:

You should `Dispose` (that also "cleans the cache") the `DbContext` as soon as possible, and modern C# syntax does this perfectly.

```cs
// Code of current method

using (var context = new AppDbContext())
{
  var firstProduct = context.Products.FirstOrDefault();

  if (firstProduct != null)
  {
    // Update the price of the first product
    firstProduct.Price = 9.99m;

    // Save the changes to the database
    context.SaveChanges();
}

// Other code of current method
```

Creation of `DbContext` itself is really fast. The slow part is establishing the connection with SQL Server. This is easily optimized with connection pooling. A single line in `Program.cs` is enough to turn it on.

```cs
services.AddDbContext<EmployeeContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));
```

The most of the caching is done on the SQL Server part.

- It caches results of the query - so receiving two identical queries will result in second one to be returned from cache
- It tries to convert every query into a parametrized query so another query of identical structure but different parameters is handled faster
- It saves query plan for every query so it doesn't need to recalculate what operations to do to return data for every query

EF Core and SqlServer work perfectly together. It's just like they both were made by the same company ^_^